# Scenario of implementing mixed-effects model

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, modeling, multilevel-analysis

I'm currently analyzing data with repeated measurements. However, the interested studied variables with fixed effects were collected after the occurrence of the response variables. I think usually the predictors should be collected before the response variables, like specific treatment. But I was wondering if it is still appropriate to use the linear or even non-linear mixed models to investigate the association between the interested fixed-effect variables and the repeated response measurements.

Thanks in advance.